# Add input field dynamically ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I am facing problem while adding input field dynamically,

when i click on plus button it calls AddItemData() but this function is not adding new input field to deck_array

Here is my code,

**home.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm1">
  <ion-list no-lines class="listMargin">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="labelColor" stacked>
        Ship name
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="ship_name" type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div formArrayName="deck_array" style="background-color:white">
      <ion-list *ngFor="let obj of myForm1.controls.deck_array.controls;let i=index">
        <div>
          <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-input [formControlName]="i" placeholder="select from list or type in"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-item style="background-color: transparent">
    <button item-start ion-fab mini color="dark" (click)="AddItemData('')">
      Add New field            
     <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

response from server i have received in **pData**,consider in below format

**home.ts**

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.pData = {
    "ship_name": "Abit smith",
    "deck_array": [
      "MD 1",
      "MD 2"
    ],
  };

  this.myForm1 = this._fb.group({
    ship_name: [this.pData.ship_name],
    deck_array: this._fb.array([])
  });
  this.AddItemData(this.pData.deck_array);
  console.log(this.myForm1.value);
}

AddItemData(item) {
  const arrayControl = ( < FormArray > this.myForm1.get('deck_array'));
  const controls = item.map(value => this._fb.control(value));
  controls.forEach(control => arrayControl.push(control));
}
```

*why it is not adding, can any one help me?*

***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: Can you provide the stackblitz to show the issue?

Comment: when i click on plus button it calls `AddItemData()` but this function is not adding new input field to `deck_array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template:

```
<button item-start ion-fab mini color="dark" (click)="addItem()">
  Add New field            
  <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
addItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.myForm1.get('deck_array')).push(this._fb.control(''));
}
```